# Wordpress 3.2.0 Need help localizing Date format to Spanish in comment meta

Tags: wordpress, date, comments, translate

I´m working on a blog for a Spanish client:

http://www.microcementoeuropeo.com/blog/

The theme was created from scratch and I have been manually translating english text for comments form etc. However - i´ve run into a problem with the date format in the comments meta which displays as:

07/11/2011 at 8:10 pm

...which I need to change to:

07/11/2011 a las 8:10 pm

I´ve tried changing the format in the general settings of the wordpress install and searched in the comments.php file but to no avail. Any clues appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a WP install at hand to try this but I think you can use the_date() and the_time() functions. Something like this:

```
<p>Posted: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> a las <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></p>
```

You may need to changed the parameters to each function to match your format.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_time

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! - However my problem is not so much understanding the syntax but where to find the file in which to edit the code. I´ve just found commment-template.php which has the line: function get_comment_time( $d = '', $gmt = false, $translate = true ) so I'm assuming this means the time format will be translated according to the configuration of the users system.

Comment: That's the file where that function is defined. Your theme may or may not use it. In your theme directory (wordpress/wp-content/themes/<name>/) you should see a file called comments.php. In there may be a line like this: wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'FUNC!' ) ); Open up functions.php and see if the value of 'FUNC!' from comments.php is a function in here. If it is, then this function is your comments output. But themes can do any old thing so this may not hold true. Are you using a freely downloadbale theme?